# Is a RJ12 port for a cash drawer a Coms port in window7

Tags: .net, serial-port

I am trying to open a cash drawer on a [Aures Yuno](http://www.aures.com/uk/point-of-sale-equipment-solutions-systems/yuno-touchscreen-terminal-multi-configuration) running windows 7 the port is a RJ12 port with the cash drawer directly connected.

The [manual](http://support.j2rs.com/Documents/TechnicalDocs/YUNO_User_Manual_V1.0(EN).pdf) states on page 22 it that the register location is 48Ch which a cash drawer tester can open using direct O/I addressing.

can anyone tell how I access this port and would it be a coms so I can just use SerialPort() in .net.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to connect the cash drawer using a different computer's serial port?
Or do you trying to operate the drawer with the Yuno?
Doe's the Yuno came with some kind of API? is seems like this is not serial port but some kind of GPIO.

Comment: I am just using the Yuno.

Comment: Is it an option to use the .exe they gave to control the drawer using Process.Start()?
Looks to me like the most simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is parallel port not serial port. You need to use parallel port api provided by windows. However do note that windows uses printer class for parallel port activities.